# Find cell value in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have to excel sheet and, using vba, I would like to get a value in one of those, search it in the other one and return a correspondant value in the first sheet.

Given the sheet 1:

[image]

I would like to search the string I inserted in A5 in another sheet:

Sheet 2:

[image]

Once I found the match (A2 in this case), I would get the 'value' (in D2 in this case) and report it in the cell B5 of the Sheet1.

That's what I tried:

```
Dim rgFound As Range
Dim defVal As Range
Dim currParam As Range
Dim currParamDict As Range

For Each defVal In Range("B:B")

    Set currParam = Cells(Range(defVal).Row, Range(defVal).Column - 1)
    If currParam Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Name was not found."        
    End If

    Set rgFound = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(currParam.value)
    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Name was not found."
    Else
        Set currParamDict = Cells(Range(rgFound).Row, Range(rgFound).Column + 3)
        defVal.value = currParamDict.value
    End If
Next defVal
```

That's clearly wrong since the compiler gives me an error on Range at the line:

```
Set currParam = Cells(Range(defVal).Row, Range(defVal).Column - 1)
```

Comment: You should use worksheet variables where you can store the two worksheet objects you want to work with. This will allow you to use explicit references to range objects belonging to the worksheets which in turn will help you keep better track of what you are doing.

Comment: For **every** `Range` and `Cells` please specify in which sheet it is. Eg. `Worksheets("MySheetName").Range`

Comment: ^^ and `Set currParam = Cells(defVal.Row, defVal.Column - 1)` as `defval` is a range itself. Btw this is equivalent to `defval.offset(,-1)`. And it will never be `Nothing` as you've just defined it.

Comment: Why don't you just use VLOOKUP?

Comment: would be great to use it but I am facing problem in accessing to cell values dinamycally

Comment: Using the INDEX, MATCH formula will do this for you without code:
INDEX, MATCH is broken down into 3 main Parts:
The values you want to return, the value you want to match and the value list you want to lookup.
Place the below formula into Sheet1 Cell B5 and Replace your sheet names accordingly (if required):
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$5, MATCH(Sheet1!$A5, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,0))

Comment: but in this case I don't have the flexibility of setting a dinamic range in which search and in which put values.

Comment: @SJR Or, if this *has* to be VBA, `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` or `WorksheetFunction.Match` and `Worksheet.Cell`

Comment: @Chronocidal- aye, I followed OP's approach but could be worth another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub x()

Dim rgFound As Range
Dim defVal As Range
Dim currParam As Range
Dim currParamDict As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each defVal In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
        Set currParam = defVal.Offset(, -1)
        If Len(currParam.Value) > 0 Then
            Set rgFound = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(currParam.Value)
            If rgFound Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Name was not found."
            Else
                Set currParamDict = rgFound.Offset(, 3)
                defVal.Value = currParamDict.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next defVal
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ok, it gave me the correct result. Unfortunately it also raised an error: method Find of object Range failed.

on 
Set rgFound = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(currParam.value)

Comment: I've amended the code above as problem may be a blank cell, but that line is not in my code.

Comment: The name of the string I have inserted. I think the function is triggered a second time because of the modification caused by defVal.value = currParamDict.value (the code is in a Worksheet_Change sub)

Comment: You didn't mention that. You need to disable events. I meant what is its specific value when it errors?

Comment: Why do you not have any reference to `Target`?

Comment: ok I have added an intersect for the column. Thanks a lot for the help